# DMG or Package Installer

Tags: mac, dmg

If I need to download an App, what method of installer should I prefer DMG or Package Installer? Which has greater advantage.

Comment: Is the application for use on your personal Mac or for deployment on multiple Macs? The advantages will depend on how you intend to deploy and maintain the application.

Answer (score 2):

DMG is easy drag and drop install for softwares that don't require specific installations;

Package Installer is for softwares who need to have specific parts installed in a specific place (libraries, plug-ins...)

I would prefer the first one, because you can make easy and clean (un)installation with 1 mouse's click.